# JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK in KonyStudio

Tags: ant, java-home, temenos-quantum

I have running a simple app in Konystudio. i got the follwing error

```
[exec-shell] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
[exec-shell] Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
[exec-shell] It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
[exec-shell]
```

But my

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\;
ANT_HOME = C:\KonyOne\Ant
Path  = C:\KonyOne\ImageMagick;C:\KonyOne\Ant\bin;
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\yuvarajag\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;D:\Tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk;
```

i have set all the path correctly but not able to run the application.

i didn't set path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" anywhere.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `java/bin` and android tools and platform-tools path onto your `Path` variable.

> Path : "C:\Kony\ImageMagick;C:\Kony\Ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Android\tools;C:\Android\platform-tools"

This is needed to show the app that has been built on your emulator.